# Allow to retract all my votes on the election

Tags: feature-request, moderator-election

Well, I was testing something with the election page, and afterwards intended to retract my votes. I intended to do like upvotes/downvotes, just click again and the vote disappear, well, it doesn't. I could select other candidates but that doesn't achieve what I want. Could this be made possible?

The method suggested by [timaschew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310798/792066) does indeed remove all my votes, it seems to be a no brainer for this to be enabled on the election page itself, along with the possibility of retracting one vote.

This is a **feature request**, while the other question is support (through it says discussion...)

Comment: found a solution: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310798/736518

Comment: We already discussed (on deleted comments) that this is not a duplicate in previous comments, since the other meta question isn't actionable by a developer, while *this* is.

Comment: How should the [Constituent badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) be handled if a user retracts their votes?

Comment: @PetahChristian the same way it's done for critic, supporter, editor, etc. Stack Exchange doesn't retract a badge if you won it, except for tag badges.

Comment: Since [the Constituent badge is a factor in determining the Candidate Score](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289504/4151918), perhaps we should consider how vote retraction would skew perception of a user's participation.

Comment: @PetahChristian that would be possible, but I doubt someone trying to play the badges to aim for moderator would plan that ahead.

Answer (score 16):

Without any magic you only can retract 2 of your 3 choices, by overwriting your choices.

I found out to retract the last choice with these steps:

1. Open the developer toolbar of your browser and go to the network tab
2. Just set any choice to a random user
3. Find the XHR item in the network tab and use the context menu (right mouse click) and choose **Copy as cURL** (I'm using chrome, not sure where to find this in another browser)
4. Paste the clipboard into a terminal
5. At the end you should see something like `&voteIndex=1'`. Just set the number to `0` and press Enter

You should get this answer:

> {"Success":false,"Message":"Invalid vote cast","NewScore":0}

Now go back to your browser and refresh the page ;)